# ruby cucumber verify field validation errors

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, browser-automation

In our application, if we click on submit button with out entering any value we get an field validation error ( screenshot below ), can you please guide me how to handle it with Ruby Cucumber

in below screenshot we have a popup saying "please select an item in the list" which needs to be verified

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about the behavior including the purpose of what is happening.

```
Given I am creating a relationship that doesn't include the relationship type
When I save the relationship
Then I am asked to select a relationship type
And the relationship is not yet saved
```

It focuses on what is being done, less on the technology details of dropdown, the technology of the message, more on what is supposed to happen.

Comment: we are in to automation side, i mean part of implementation. we are looking for a solution on how to automate.